# setting offset to category number in archive page

Tags: wp-query, query, archive-template, offsets

unit test data added many category to some posts.so, on archive page, the long category list seems bad because you know its long, ugly.

so, to solve this visual problem, I want to set offset to this category number.

How can I do it?

here is my archive page.I tried to add offset to the wp query but it doesnt work.

you can check the archive page with this link:

https://unit-test-data.deniz-tasarim.site/category/edge-case-2/

( Edge Case: Many Categories )

archive.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<main role="main">
    <?php get_template_part( 'breadcrumb' );?>
    <section class="ulockd-service-details">
        <div class="container">
            <?php hekim_left_sidebar(); ?>
            <?php hekim_col_sidebar(); ?>
                <div class="row">
<?php
                    //To retrieve current category id dynamically
                    $current_cat = get_the_category();
                    $cat_ID = $current_cat[0]->cat_ID;

                    $loop = new WP_Query(array(
                    'offset' => 2,         //Set your offset
                    'cat' => $cat_ID,      //The category id
                    ));
?>


                    <?php if ($loop->have_posts()): while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
                <?php
                if ( $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id() ) {
                       ?>
                    <div class="col-md-12 ulockd-mrgn1210">
                        <div class="ulockd-project-sm-thumb">
                            <img class="img-responsive img-whp" style="width: 368px; max-height: 580px;" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(array(1100, 550)); ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
                    <div class="col-md-12 ulockd-mrgn1210">
                        <article class="ulockd-pd-content">
                            <div class="ulockd-bp-date">
                                <ul class="list-inline">
                                    <?php
                                    if ( class_exists( 'Redux' ) ) {
                                        global $redux_demo;
                                        if ($redux_demo['button-set-date-choose'] == 1)
                                        {
                                            ?>
                                            <li class="ulockd-bp-date-innner"><?php _e( 'On ', 'hekim' )?><a href="#"><span class="text-thm2"><?php the_time('j'); ?></span> / <?php the_time('F Y') ?></a></li>
                                            <?php
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            ?>
                                            <li class="ulockd-bp-date-innner"><?php _e( 'On ', 'hekim' )?><a href="#"><span class="text-thm2"><?php the_time(); ?></span></a></li>
                                            <?php
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        ?>
                                        <li class="ulockd-bp-date-innner"><?php _e( 'On ', 'hekim' )?><a href="#"><span class="text-thm2"><?php the_time(); ?></span></a></li>
                                        <?php
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                    <li class="ulockd-bp-comment"><a href="#"><span class="flaticon-nurse-head text-thm1"></span> <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></a></li>
                                    <li class="ulockd-bp-comment"><a href="#"><span class="flaticon-chat text-thm1"></span> <?php if (comments_open( get_the_ID() ) ) comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave your thoughts', 'hekim' ), __( '1 Comment', 'hekim' ), __( '% Comments', 'hekim' )); ?></a></li>
                                    <li class="ulockd-bp-comment"><a href="#"><span class="flaticon-black-check-box text-thm1"></span> <?php the_category(); ?></a></li>

                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <h3><?php the_title(); ?> </h3>
                            <p class="project-dp-one"><?php the_excerpt(); //html5wp_excerpt('html5wp_index'); // Build your custom callback length in functions.php ?></p>
                            <a class="btn btn-lg ulockd-btn-thm2" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php _e( ' Read More', 'hekim' )?></a>
                        </article>
                    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else: ?>
                    <article>
                        <h2><?php _e( 'Sorry, nothing to display.', 'hekim' )?></h2>
                    </article>
<?php endif; ?>
                    <?php get_template_part( 'pagination' ); ?>
                </div></div><?php hekim_right_sidebar(); ?>
        </div></section>
                    <?php get_footer(); ?>
</main>
```

Comment: Can you explain in different words what you meant in your first sentence? I don't understand how the post offset is related to the number of categories. I also strongly advise against using a replacement `WP_Query` loop, if you want to change the posts the main query fetches, use the `pre_get_posts` filter

Comment: @TomJNowell I meant that there are many added categories for some posts but my theme design has maximum 4 category name capasity.so, I want to show only maximum 4 different category name for every post.